# Simple algebra of integral

Tags: integration, time-series, continuous-variables

I'm studying economics and I'm having trouble with math calculations. 
In my economics textbook, the following equation comes out, and for me it's hard to understand how this relationship is established.
I know a very basic concept of calculus, so could you explain the formula below in detail?
Thank you.
**Note**. Everything is a continuous concept

- $t$ is the time index,
- $\pi(K(t))$ is the profit function with capital($K$),
- $r$ is the interest rate,
- $e^{-rt} = (1+r)^t$ (at least in the limit),
- $q(t)$ is the cost function,
- $\dot q(t)$ is the time derivative of $q(t)$,
- $\pi(K(t))=r\cdot q(t)-\dot q(t)$

For arbitrary $T>t$, the relationship below is established.
$$
q(t)=\int\limits_{\tau=t} ^\infty e^{-r(\tau-t)}\pi(K(\tau))d\tau+e^{-r(T-t)}q(T)
$$

Comment: Please define what these functions are supposed to represent

Comment: @KamalSaleh I edited my question

Comment: The lower limit of integration currently reads $\tau$, which is probably not correct. Did you mean $T$?

Comment: @EricNathanStucky In my textbook it is written as $\tau=t$

Comment: Hm, then something is still amiss. For instance, if you take that whole integral and subtract it from both sides, doesn't the (new) left side not depend on $T$, but the (new) right side does? Is $T$ truly arbitrary, or are we thinking of it as growing out to infinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're doing something along the lines of a present value computation, where you are trying to look at costs into the future; since currency is worth less as time goes on, those costs can be backward-extrapolated to the present day and you can see how much of a burden they are in today's dollars.

You probably remember from calculus that $\int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\,dx = f(a)-f(b)$; this is one of the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus and basically it's what we always use to solve integrals. We apply this principle for $f(x)= q(x)e^{-r(x-t)}$, and $a=t$ and $b=T$. Recalling the product and chain rules for derivatives, this yields
\begin{align*}
\int_t^T\left[\dot q(x)e^{-r(x-t)}-q(x)re^{-r(x-t)}\right]\,dx &= q(T)e^{-r(T-t)}-q(t)e^0 \\
\int_t^T -\left[-\dot q(x)+q(x)r\right]e^{-r(x-t)}\,dx &= q(T)e^{-r(T-t)}-q(t) \\
q(t)-\int_t^T e^{-r(x-t)}\pi(K(x))\,dx &= e^{-r(T-t)}q(T) \\
\end{align*}
Adding the integral to both sides yields the given equation, except that the upper limit is $T$ instead of $\infty$.* I suspect your text is taking the limit as $T\to\infty$ (in practical terms: looking at the costs further and further into the future), in which case the $T$ in the integral does become an $\infty$, but we have to figure out what happens to the "extra" right-hand side term for large $T$. So I'm hoping the next bit of the text is devoted to that; but do let me know if I'm off base.

(* And my variable of integration is $x$ instead of $\tau$. This doesn't matter; it's just a name. Remember that when you have $\int_a^b g(x)dx$, all that matters is that you plug in $x=a$ and $x=b$ at the end, and then the $x$ has disappeared. So of course we can just as well call it $\tau$. I chose the notation that stuck closer to a calculus course than to your text so that the theory part would look more familiar.)

Comment: Yes, you're right! I skipped the latter part(infinity part) because I thought it doesn't matter, but thank you for pointing it out.